# 2001 ford explorer water leak

Tags: engine, ford, leak, explorer, water

I put water In the radiator of this vehicle I just bought and water just leaks right out from behind the fan pulley somewhere on the engine. I have checked the hoses and they're all good. Help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine does your Explorer have in it?

Comment: I don't know it is a v6 that's all I know it was purchased from a private owner and bought for parts for another Explorer which was recently totalled.  We were considering whether or not to fix or sell or salvage.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from behind the fan pulley

That's where the thermostat housing is. You should check the hoses where they connect to the thermostat housing and check the housing itself. The water pump is also back there, there is a small weep-hole at the bottom of the water pump cover to let you know when it is time to change the pump. Check the entire water pump cover as well.

You need to get a flashlight and get in there and find the leak, nobody on this site can do that for you. The thermostat and water pump are good starting points.

Comment: We did check all the hoses around and they were OK. WE don't know it is a v6 that's all I know it was purchased from a private owner and bought for parts for another Explorer which was recently totalled. We were considering whether or not to fix or sell or salvage.  It is realky a very tight space to work in. Hard to get behind the pulley. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In general, coolant leaks can be deceiving in origin because of two things:

1 - It's mostly transparent so easy to visually miss; and
2 - It tends to leak when the system is hot and under pressure. When cold, even with the engine running, the system is only slightly above ambient pressure (there will be some pressure due to the pumping action of the water pump). When hot, pressure builds up to around 15 psi depending on the system to increase the boiling point of the coolant. Unfortunately, leaking coolant evaporates quickly on hot surfaces, making finding small leaks hard to find.

I would highly recommend getting a coolant testing kit from the parts store. I know the local Autozone loans them out for free and I'm sure other stores do also. It allows you to pressurize the system when the engine cold and not running so you can take your time and find leaks, and not worry about hot surfaces or getting shredded by the fan or belt. I had no fewer than 4 small coolant leaks on my vehicle (a V6 Explorer) at the heater hose connections due to bad clamps that I found using a tester.

Based on your description (and assuming you have one of the V6 engines) I would guess you have a thermostat housing leak, a heater hose leak, a water pump leak (either the seal or weep hole, either way the pump should be replaced), or a timing cover leak (if you are really unlucky).